# How to return raw text and maintain its shape and structure?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I create a mini-application where users can [paste](https://www.bunlongheng.com/paste) any texts & share it. Let's say the user inputs these texts below.

Ex.

```
╔══╗
╚╗╔╝
╔╝(¯`v´¯)
╚══`.¸.[Stackoverflow]
```

When I load it on textarea, it displays correctly.

[image]

[Link](https://www.bunlongheng.com/paste/OTdlZDkyNjgtZjIxYi00YTYyLWFmNjctMzZiOGVjN2I1NGNh)

But when I return raw of that

I kept getting display inline (***broken***)

```
╔══╗ ╚╗╔╝ ╔╝(¯`v´¯) ╚══`.¸.[Stackoverflow]
```

[Link](https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/OTdlZDkyNjgtZjIxYi00YTYyLWFmNjctMzZiOGVjN2I1NGNh)

---

All I did was this

```
public function raw($uuid)
{
    $paste  = Paste::where('uuid', base64_decode($uuid))->first();

    if($paste->type == 'json'){
        return response()->json($paste->data);
    } else {
        return $paste->raw;
    }
    
}
```

How can I maintain the same format as I would have render it in my textarea ?

---

Ex 2.

[Display in text-area](https://www.bunlongheng.com/paste/ZDE5ZjdhNjMtYjQwNS00OTU5LTg5ZWItNTdhNzEwZTFiMmRl)

```
▀██▀─▄███▄─▀██─██▀██▀▀█
─██─███─███─██─██─██▄█
─██─▀██▄██▀─▀█▄█▀─██▀█
▄██▄▄█▀▀▀─────▀──▄██▄▄█
```

[Raw Response](https://www.bunlongheng.com/raw/ZDE5ZjdhNjMtYjQwNS00OTU5LTg5ZWItNTdhNzEwZTFiMmRl)

As you can see in raw it displays so bad ...

```
▀██▀─▄███▄─▀██─██▀██▀▀█ ─██─███─███─██─██─██▄█ ─██─▀██▄██▀─▀█▄█▀─██▀█ ▄██▄▄█▀▀▀─────▀──▄██▄▄█
```

---

## Edit

If I wrap it around **pre** tag

```
return '<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">'. $paste->raw.'</textarea>';
```

I get a better result

[image]

Comment: The browser removes the new lines. If you view the source, it looks ok.

Comment: Is there a way to force to maintain the text structure? I've tried wrapping it around the `pre` tag

Comment: Did you try `white-space: pre;` ?

Comment: Was it a css u want me to apply to my pre tag ?

Comment: what about pre-wrap .  return "<div style='white-space: pre-wrap;'>╔══╗
╚╗╔╝
╔╝(¯`v´¯)
╚══`.¸.[Stackoverflow]</div>";

Comment: @cyb3rZ your PHP looks good to me. It's likely just the CSS handling of that element. I just submitted my solution which should resolve the issue.

Comment: @cyb3rZ can you please check my solution when you have a chance? I would like to assist with your "return" (raw response) logic as you mentioned in your question so that we can make the line breaks persistent. Please respond when you have a chance with your findings.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of having to wrap the text in `<pre></pre>` tags, just apply the CSS property `white-space: pre` to whichever textarea or other element you are collecting that text in.

Here is the documentation for the `pre` CSS property: [MDN Web Docs: `white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

That will force the line breaks to be respected. That should also copy & paste just fine. Your existing solution already appears to copy and paste just fine for me as well. Make sure to use a monospace font for that text box, as that is necessary to keep all the columns in line.

You can find plenty of great, free monospace font options here on Google Fonts: https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace

## Examples

#### **Without** `white-space: pre`

** Make sure to click the "Run code snippet" button below to see the rendered preview

```html
<div id="ascii-art" contenteditable>╔══╗
╚╗╔╝
╔╝(¯`v´¯)
╚══`.¸.[Stackoverflow]</div>
```

#### ✅ **With** `white-space: pre` and a monospace font

** Make sure to click the "Run code snippet" button below to see the rendered preview

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap');

#ascii-art {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="ascii-art" contenteditable>╔══╗
╚╗╔╝
╔╝(¯`v´¯)
╚══`.¸.[Stackoverflow]</div>
```

## BONUS

If you would like to get all the characters tight and up against each other, add the CSS below:

```css
white-space: pre;
font-family: consolas;
letter-spacing: -0.3px;
line-height: 1.19;
```

The letter-spacing and line-height values will need to be adjusted slightly as you change the font-family and font-size. Here is that CSS in action for both artworks you provided:

```css
#ascii-art {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: consolas;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  line-height: 1.19;
}
```

```html
<div id="ascii-art" contenteditable>▀██▀─▄███▄─▀██─██▀██▀▀█
─██─███─███─██─██─██▄█
─██─▀██▄██▀─▀█▄█▀─██▀█
▄██▄▄█▀▀▀─────▀──▄██▄▄█

╔══╗
╚╗╔╝
╔╝(¯`v´¯)
╚══`.¸.[Stackoverflow]</div>
```

Comment: Wow.  Extra points for the Bonus - very nice add!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it not inside `<pre>` which by default preserves new-line chars and also uses monospace font.

1. Use in style of html tag or in css. `font-family: monospace;`
2. Prepare your string by replacing `\n` with `<br/>` before injecting into the html tag.

Example: `const htmlStr = myStr.replace(/\n/g,'<br/>')`

Answer (score 0):

The newline character ('\n'), is not a known html character.
It must be replaced with a break tag ('br') for the browser to recognise it.
Change your function to globally replace the '\n' with a break tag, which will be rendered by the browser the same way.

```
public function raw($uuid)
{
    $paste  = Paste::where('uuid', base64_decode($uuid))->first();

    if($paste->type == 'json')
    {
        return response()->json($paste->data);
    }
    else
    {
        return $paste->raw.replace(/\n/g,'<br>');
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe people misunderstood the question. I believe what OP is asking is how to return the result as a raw text string not part of a website. Something along the lines of old school ASCII art.

If I'm correct in that assumption then the answer is simple. Add:

```
header("content-type: text/plain");
```

before your output on the raw page. That will tell the browser to look at the content as a plain text file with end of line characters etc.